# Error when starting any program

Tags: eclipse, openedge

Each time when I start any program in OpenEdge Architect (OpenEdge Version 10.2B) or when I start the IDE I get the error.

> Can't open log file c:\temp, errno 5 (11076) [translated]

After the error the IDE or program starts normally.

Googling this error took me to following article, but the errno "5" isn't mentioned there, only 32, 13, 11. I use Windows 7 as OS. http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P134005
The article says also that this error is related to a "client-logging file". Where can I find it?

I also tried to stop the service "AdminService for OpenEdge 10.2B", but it didn't help.

What's the origin of this error?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere the `-clientlog` parameter is set. Probably:

```
-clientlog c:\temp
```

When I add this parameter to the Client shortcut (to open the Procedure Editor), then I get the same error.

When you have the error as well when you start the Procedure Editor, then have a look at:

- The Client shortcut: see what's behind `prowin32.exe`
- See if the parameter is added to `<progress-installation-dir>\startup.pf`

In Architect you can check:

- Window / Preferences -> Progress OpenEdge / Startup -> Default startup parameters
- Window / Preferences -> Progress OpenEdge / Shared AVM -> Startup parameters
- For all your OE projects: Open project context menu / Properties -> Progress OpenEdge -> Startup parameters

Comment: Thanks alot for answer, it helped me to get to the solution. It was the startup parameter `-O c:\temp` in the startup.pf. If you add this to your answer I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

That "errno 5" is the Windows error code for access denied. Try checking the permissions on that folder and give yourself write access to it.